# Temporary edits global variable

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LISP - Global variable keep their old value after reinitialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071198/lisp-global-variable-keep-their-old-value-after-reinitialization)

I'm currently doing some coursework with Lisp (using Common Lisp) and have nowhere else to turn with this problem I'm having.

It's tricky to explain but here goes..

**The situation:**
I've got two global variables, p1 & p2, which are polynomial expressions. My task is to create a polynomial calculator, which is going well so far.

I keep my polynomial elements in a specific format: 3x^2 == ((x 2) 3), and I've created two functions which recursively run through both lists of polynomial elements.

If I wanted to add together 3x^2 and 2x^2, the answer would be 5x^2 (or "((x 2) (3+2))").

I have a third list, the result, which is appended to whenever an element is calculated/can't be calculated.

**The problem:**
With two elements I can add together, I create a temporary variable to be added to the result. However, the global variable is changed despite what I do.

I've tried let, lambda, various functions, etc. I've been stuck for a couple of days now and would greatly appreciate any help you could give me :)

**Here's a small example of what I mean:**

```
(setf p1 '((x 2) 2))
    ;2x^2

(setf p2 '((x 2) 3))
    ;3x^2 

(if (equal (first p1) (first p2)) 
    (progn
      (setf temp p1)
      (setf (second temp) (+ (second p1) (second p2)))
      (append-to-result temp)
      (print p1)
      (print temp)))
```

**Output:**

> ((x 2) 5)
>
> ((x 2) 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
(setf temp p1)
```

you are not_making a copy of the list structure that `p1` refers to. Both variables now refer to the same cons cells. Then when you do:

```
(setf (second temp) ...)
```

you're modifying that list structure, which both variables still refer to.  Change to:

```
(setf temp (copy-tree p1))
```